# Nested attributes not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, fabrication-gem

I have a User class which can have many Payments.
The User will get saved but the payments are not.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :payments, :payments_attributes
  attr_accessible :payments_attributes, :payments
  has_many :payments, :inverse_of => :user, :autosave => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, allow_destroy: false
end

class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # it looks that I do not need the attr_accessor methods
  #attr_accessor :method, :paid, :amount, :creditcard, :security_code, :expires_at

  attr_accessible :method, :paid, :amount, :creditcard, :security_code, :expires_at
  attr_accessible :created_at, :user_id

  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :payments

  validates_presence_of :method
end
```

I have tried this approach:

```
User.create!( { email: "asdf@asdf.com", payments: {paid: false, method: "bank"} } )
```

Is there a solution to do this without passing:

```
u = User.new(params)
u.payments(payments_params)
u.save!
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like this should work:

```
User.create!( { 
  "email" =>  "asdf@asdf.com", 
  "payments_attributes" => [{paid: false, method: "bank"}] 
} )
```

Comment: Then I get: ```ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: payments[] ``` And I use ```attr_accessor :payments, :payments_attributes
  attr_accessible :payments_attributes, :payments```

Comment: Whoops, forgot the `_attributes` piece. `payments_attributes[]` should work for you.

Comment: Same problem: ```ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: payments_attributes[]```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[]` at the end of `payments_attributes`?

Comment: Rolling back, sorry, payments are not saved

Comment: That's weird. If it was a validation error it would at least raise an exception.